# Shortcut to open editor type menu

Tags: python, shortcut

I would like to be able to change the currently active editor type through keyboard shortcuts only (rather than having to click twice). – is there a way to assign a shortcut to the menu? (in the menu you can simply press the underlined letters to select.)

[image]

is it maybe possible to simulate clicks on buttons with python?

---

it could also be nice to have a radial menu for this.

Comment: I prefer to change the current [screen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/screens.html) which changes multiple editors at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously the default keyboard shortcuts **@Crantisz** mentioned work. however I find them hard to remember, so I created a custom pie menu addon: [blender-editor-switcher](https://github.com/freder/blender-editor-switcher)

---

**EDIT:**
turns out this exists already, as part of https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/viewport_pies

Answer (score 4):

It's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> buttons.

You can change hotkeys in User Preferences (Input Tab) They are in a window section:

[image]